# Not able to modify shortcut path

Tags: vbscript

I am using VBscript to modify the Target Path of a shortcut but I am not able to do so. When I run the script I dont get any errors but it seems as if the script does not do anything, that is the Target Path is not changed. Here is my script

```
Private Sub Change_ShortCut(TargetPath, ShortCutPath, ShortCutname, WorkPath, ServerName, PortNumber, ServiceName, ExecVar)
Dim VbsObj
Dim userName
Dim hostName

 ' Get user name and host name from another method
 Get_UserName userName, hostName 

Const ALL_USERS_DESKTOP = &H19&
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(ALL_USERS_DESKTOP)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("App1.lnk")
Set objShellLink = objFolderItem.GetLink
Wscript.Echo objShellLink.Path
objShellLink.Path = TargetPath & ServerName & " " & PortNumber & " " & ServiceName & " " & userName & " " & hostName & " 20 -exec=" & """" & "\""" & ExecVar & "\""" &"""" 
objShellLink.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying too hard. Use a `WshShell` object instead:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

lnkpath = fso.BuildPath(sh.SpecialFolders("AllUsersDesktop"), "App1.lnk")
Set lnk = sh.CreateShortcut(lnkpath)
lnk.TargetPath = TargetPath & ServerName & " " & PortNumber & " " & ServiceName _
  & " " & userName & " " & hostName & " 20 -exec=""\""" & ExecVar & "\"""""
lnk.Save
```

If you have a domain environment, using [Group Policy Preferences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731892%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) might be a better way to updating shortcuts.